# jQuery validation error messages enlarges the glyphicons

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Whenever any error message is displayed, the glyphicon enlarges and goes out of order. Why? See the pic for reference.

[image]

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" >Ad title <sup>*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input class="form-control input-md" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like the required message is causing the container to expand. The structure of your html should change to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Can you show your code? Show us what it looks like before the error and then after the error appears (use your browser's inspector).

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever any error message is displayed, the glyphicon enlarges and goes out of order. Why?

The glyphicon does not enlarge.  When you inspect your DOM, you'll see that the Validate plugin is dynamically inserting the error message immediately after the `input` element, thereby enlarging the container and breaking your design.

The insertion of this `label` after the `input` element is the default result.  If you use your browser's tools to inspect your live DOM, you would find something like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" >Ad title <sup>*</sup></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control input-md" type="text" name="foo">
            <label id="foo-error" class="error" for="foo">This field is required.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

When designing your layout, you'll have to take this behavior into account so nothing breaks.

Otherwise, you would use [the `errorPlacement` callback](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorplacement) to edit this behavior as you see fit.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element); // <- default
}
```

Maybe you want to insert it after the parent element?

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter($(element).parent());
}
```

You can also use [the `errorElement` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorelement) to change the error element container.

```
errorElement: "label" // <- default
```

See all options:  [jqueryvalidation.org/validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I solved it with this code, just adjust it to your JavaScript code.

Code:

```
      $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        fname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },

    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',


});
```

Comment: Still the same problem.